# AttributeError: Encryption instance has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

I am tring to create a AES like crytography code and I am having errors that I need help with.

```
      File "C:\Users\work\Desktop\try.py", line 156, in byte_construct
        if (pos & array_8[i]):
    AttributeError: Encryption instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I keep getting the error above.Can somebody give me a solution. Following is my source

```
def rotate_byte_left(byte):
     value = 0x00
     value = byte & 0x80
     byte = byte << 1
     byte = byte & 0xFF
     if value == 0x80:
         byte = byte | 0x01
     return byte

def rotate_byte_right(byte):
    value = 0x00
    value = byte & 0x01
    byte = byte >> 1
    byte = byte & 0xFF
    if value == 0x01:
        byte = byte | 0x80
    return byte

def byte_construct(array_8,bit_pos):
    byte = 0x00
    for p in bit_pos:
        pos = (0x01 << p)
    for i in range(0,8): Specifically the error is poiting here.
        if (pos & array_8[i]):
            byte = byte & (0x01 << bit_pos)
    return byte

def addRoundKey(self, state, roundKey):
    """Adds (XORs) the round key to the state."""
    for i in range(0, len(state)):
        state[i] ^= roundKey[i]
    return state       

def ecb(self, plaintext, key):
    start = time.time()
    pre_round1 = self.convert_hex_to_list(plaintext ^ key)
    substitution_result = self.subBytes(pre_round1, False)
    permutaion_result = self.byte_construct(substitution_result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    encrypt = Encryption()
    encrypt.ecb(0x0000000000000000, 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF)
    print encrypt.convert_list_to_hex([255,0,255])
```

Comment: this probably means your `array_8` is not indexable, i.e. you cannot write `array_8[i]`

Comment: Aside: calling a module `try` is a bad idea because since that's a Python keyword you can't import it using something like `import try`.

Comment: You post haven't enough data to answer, please pdate method self.sunBytes and check ( or simple add print) what it returns, answer is there

Comment: It looks like you want `byte_construct` to be a `staticmethod`. Currently you're binding the `Encryption` instance to the `array_8` parameter, which obviously doesn't implement `__getitem__`. Also, the call `self.byte_construct(substitution_result)` is missing the required argument for `bit_pos`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `byte_construct()` is not a instance method of the class Encryption, but you are calling it like it is

```
permutation_result = self.byte_construct(substitution_result)
```

What this means is that now `byte_construct` would use `self` as its first argument (`array-8` in this case), and `substitution_result` as its second argument (`bit_pos`). Since `self` is an Encryption object, which I'm guessing is not meant to be indexed (i.e. you didn't define `self.__getitem__()` for it), you've got the above error.

Comment: so what will be the solution can you please provide it here ?

Comment: the solution is that you have to look closely at the declaration of `byte_construct()` and adjust your invocation of it accordingly. Currently you are invoking it like a instance method of the Encryption class, but it's not defined as such (i.e. it's not defined within the Encryption class and it doesn't take self as its first argument). Ask yourself: what type should `array_8` be? If it should be an Encryption object, then make `byte_construct` an instance method. If it shouldn't, then remove the `self.` prefix when you call it, and provide it with the object that should be `array_8`.